# Checking, if multiple integers are bigger than one integer

Tags: java, variables

I am trying to write an `if` statement that checks if 3 numbers are each greater than 20 (for example).

This is what I thought would work:

```
x = 30;
y = 40;
z = 60;

if ((x&y&z) > 20) {
    System.out.println("true");
}
```

Sadly, it doesn't work that way. Can anyone help me?

*NOTE:* I do know you can do

```
if (blabla && blabla && blabla) {
```

I just want a quicker way.

Comment: You are checking to see if *each* of them is bigger than 20 ? Or all 3 put together ?

Comment: if each of them is bigger than 20.

Comment: @MannyD: That falls flat on its face if any number is greater than 60.

Comment: @CaptainSkyhawk, yep, just realized that.

Comment: @werter318 You can't really get around it for the all condition. Any would be easy. Single `&` performs a bitwise AND operation, drastically different than logical AND `&&`

Comment: (x&y&z) won't work as if x has more digits then y and y has more digits then z then there's a chance that MSB of x and y and z can be zeroed. for an example, (20&32&64) = 0

Comment: x = 30>20; y = 40>20; z = 60>20; if(x&y&z)System.out.println("True"); This won't be very efficient as there're 3 comparisons as well but it has the beauty of bitwise AND :-)

Comment: What you're really looking for here is a partial function that you can apply to an arbitrary list of inputs. Scala (and other functional languages) provide this, but plain Java does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by *quicker* you mean quicker to type, then I think you're out of luck. But note that

```
x > 20 && y > 20 && z > 20
```

is short-circuit, so you really can't get any more efficient, since you will have to perform at least one comparison per variable anyway.

Also, just for your own personal enlightenment, `&` is the [bitwise-AND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operator when used with integer arguments (as you are using it), and it is the non-short-circuit logical-AND operator when used with booleans.

Comment: Well, if it can't be more efficient I know enough thanks for the answer!

Comment: `&` and also non-short circuit logical and operator

Comment: @SteveKuo OK, I made that clarification. Was that the reason for the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

There's no quicker way to write that down than the "blabla". If you have considerably more than 3 numbers to compare, you'd use some loop. But I guess you know that already.

Also note that a single `&` has a different meaning than the `&&`.

Comment: I suspected that, but I just didn't know the real meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The statement you wrote has no sense, since integers can't really be connected with a & sign to determine which one of the three is bigger. (Unless you're intentionally working with the bit level, which I believe is not the case).

If you want to make it a single boolean expression (That is, use > only once), I'd suggest you do something like this:

if (Math.min(x, Math.min(y,z)) > 20){
...
}

Not sure how much shorter that is then 3 separate booleans.

Edit:
Forgot to say, this is of course much less efficient then 3 booleans in terms of running time. However, if it's just comparing 3 integers you want and you don't care about how efficient it is (since really, it's not like you can see the difference in most cases), this would work.

Edit 2:
Clarified what I meant by the first sentence.

Comment: actually you should learn bitwise AND operator before calling other non sense :)

Comment: How does the bitwise AND opperator help in this case?

Comment: it doesn't help him, I've mentioned that in a comment to his question. but, "The statement you wrote has no sense, since integers can't really be connected with a & sign." is false. integers can be connected(!) with & sign.

Comment: Edited to reflect what I actually meant. Thanks.